# Unable to git fetch - Connection reset by peer

Tags: git, ssh, ssh-keys

I have a PHP script handling the automatic deploy to my pre-production server, using [Bitbucket's hooks](https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/BITBUCKET/Manage+Bitbucket+hooks). The deploy script is [based on this post](http://jonathannicol.com/blog/2013/11/19/automated-git-deployments-from-bitbucket/).

Everything was working fine until this Sunday. Since then, the automatic deploy stopped working. If I `cd` into my git repository from the preprod server and do a manual `git fetch`, I get the generic and unexpressive:

```
Read from socket failed: Connection reset by peer
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
```

I made sure my ssh `id_rsa` key is well copied to BitBucket. It would have been very surprising overwise, as I hadn't touched it since the script has been operating.

Here are the different permissions assigned :

```
$ ls -al ~ | grep .ssh                                      
drwx------  2 local local     4096 mars  13 13:28 .ssh  

$ ls -al ~/.ssh                                                                             
-rw-r--r--  1 local local  802 mars  11 17:11 authorized_keys                                            
-rw-r--r--  1 local local   51 mars  11 18:16 config
-rw-------  1 local local 1675 mars  12 17:44 id_rsa
-rw-r--r--  1 local local  396 mars  12 17:44 id_rsa.pub                                           
-rw-------  1 local local 1326 mars  25 17:38 known_hosts   
-rw-r--r--  1 local local 1326 mars  11 18:34 known_hosts.old
```

So as I can't `git fetch` my remote repository, so does my server, and the (automatic) deploy just can't happen. I can't find why SSH is refusing to work. I tried with several keys and users the all afternoon.

Any suggestion is most welcome.

Comment: "Connection reset by peer" means the remote (server) process closed the TCP connection abnormally. One thing that can cause this is if the server process is crashing. You need to troubleshoot this on the server, not the client.

Comment: Many thanks for this piece of advice. The server in my case is Bitbucket unfortunately... I can't check anything on that side I am affraid.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure remote url in your local repo is the same as Bitbucket shows for your repo on the site

```
git remote -v
```

On Bitbucket site: go to project page -> Actions -> Clone -> check url or just clone it from scratch